# Azure Bastion Host: Login using Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-bastion

I have created a windows VM on Azure. Users can log in to the VM using Active Directory credentials. Also, no public IP is associated with VM; hence, Bastion Host is the only possible way to access the VM.

Can anyone please help me understand how I can provide active directory credentials to bastion host so that I can log in to VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to virtual machines using Azure Bastion relies on either an SSH key or username/password, and currently does not support the use of Azure AD credentials.